# How to set canvas (paint view) on top of listview and still have listview clickable?

Tags: android, listview

I have a layout that contains a ListView and a few buttons in a RelativeLayout. I am trying to let the user draw on the page using a custom paint view layout. The good news is that I've got nearly everything working and looking how it should, however the last and most frustrating issue is that the ListView is no longer clickable at all. I would like to paint on top of the the ListView AND make it clickable.

The funny part is that the buttons on the page are still clickable, just the items in the ListView are not. I think what is happening is that the ListView is loaded by an adapter and gets loaded first (thus behind everything). What do I need to do in order to make the ListView clickable?

I've tried adding android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:focusable="true" but it made no difference.

My layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ></ListView>

    <com.my.app.PaintView
    android:id="@+id/paintView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<Button
    Buttons Here.../>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a solution that works perfectly (at least for me). I imagine without the listview this would have been far easier, but I wanted the listview to work as well as drawing on the canvas. All I ended up having to do was set an onTouchListener in the main activity that had the ListView, then send it to the PaintView with the MotionEvent. Simple and it works perfectly:

```
        listview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
          paintView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

            return false;
          }
        });
```

In this example, the paintView.onTouchEvent could really be any method in the custom view, just kept it at "onTouchEvent" for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

The `focusable` attribute should be `false` for the element you do **not** want to receive touch events. To overlay your `PaintView` without having it intercept touch events, you can add a few XML attributes to it:

```
<com.my.app.PaintView
    ...
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false" />
```

As long as you don't set an `OnClickListener` or an `OnTouchListener` to your PaintView, touch events should simply pass through it to the Views behind it.

Comment: The PaintView does have an onTouchEvent, it is needed so that it actually draws the line on top of the view (this is a drawing app).

Comment: Then, unfortunately, the only way for you to do this is to manually handle your PaintView's `onTouch` events and `return false` when the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` should not be handled (causing the PaintView to longer receive the touch events until another ACTION_DOWN on the View is triggered), thus passing the event to the Views behind it. It could be something as simple as a storing a class-level `boolean paintDrawingAllowed` and checking against it inside `onTouch`, or a bit more complex like ensuring the touch position is within valid Rects for drawing, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but didn't work for me because the touch didn't want to work on the listview and canvas at same time. It was one or the other. Managed to find my own solution, will post soon.